# UNITY HDRP. How to change shadow filtering quality in code

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to make settings button which change shadow filtering quality. But idk how make it in code. My code example:

```
    public void OnValueChanged()
    {
        //i need this action here
    }
```

[In-unity project settings screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4yCnC.png)

google didn't help.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
    [SerializeField]
private HDShadowResolution shadowResolution;

private void Awake()
{
    // change shadows quality
    QualitySettings.shadows = ShadowQuality.All;
    QualitySettings.shadowResolution = ShadowResolution.VeryHigh;
}
```

try this.